# What does the term "Verifleation" refer to?

Tags: vocabulary

I found the term "Verifleation" looking at [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-16492-8_96) link and had no clue what it meant so I looked it up and found no definition. Finally, after putting the term in quotes in Google I found a myriad of results using the term but still no definition. It seems that it is something related to verification, but doesn't seem to be the same thing.

If anyone finds this interesting I'd love to know your thoughts on what it might mean.

Comment: The first "Keyword" in your link is **Program Verification**. Obviously **verifleation** is a typo or OCR error. But feasibly some people have noticed the error but decided to just run with it - as in ***All your bases are belong to us*** or ***pwn = own = resoundingly beat*** in computer gaming contexts (facetiously but *deliberately* copying someone's earlier "mistake").

Comment: I'm leaving this question open because in the question itself the OP states that this *cannot* be answered with a simple dictionary search, and indeed it cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an OCR error. The paper [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1310156) seems to have a similar issue - the OCRed title of the paper is:

> FPGA based white box **verifleation** methodology for SOC design

but the scanned image under the link clearly shows that the intended word is *verification*. All the other Google hits seem to be instances of the same problem.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it seems to have adopted a meaning of its own. I've found numerous places where only typed examples make sense. https://www.numerade.com/questions/consider-the-boundary-value-problem-beginaligned-fracpartial2-upartial-t2-c2-fracpartial2-mathrmupar/. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJ8zl7D3x04. It seems I just want this to be far too much :(.

Comment: Me and my friends have decided to make it a word. To verifleate is to verify through strictly deductive means in a condescending way.

Comment: @BradOo the bad news is, even those two examples just seem to be typos of *verification*. The good news is, there's nothing stopping you from making *verifleate* a word - after all, every word started with someone just making it up and convincing people to go along with them :)

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Verifleate&defid=16805810